# Revision History for Entire Wordpress Site

Tags: php, css, git, revisions, version-control

I am learning wordpress and am working on a wordpress site where I would like to have a revision history for every single change I make. I understand you can see the revision history for pages and posts, but what about custom css + php files?

I have some experience using git and github, so I am trying to save every single change I make to my website. Having version control is not necessary, I would just like to see every single edit I have made to the file.

I am using Dreamweaver to edit the files or editing files within the wp-admin in the wordpress site.

**UPDATE: I've changed the question**

Question: Is there anyway to have Version Control/Revision History without using Git and having multiple setups of wordpress for the same site? (example: I do not need a Dev mode, Production mode, or branches) -Git seems too complicated for what I want to do

**UPDATE: I've changed the question again**

I can deal with the branches of git but I would like to be able to have git on the server automatically push any changes to the repo when I put my file to the server in dreamweaver.

Comment: You are more or less asking how to implement a comprehensive version control system. That is pretty broad.

Comment: Close... I do not want a version control system. I have no need for multiple versions... Only revision history

Comment: What is the difference between "multiple versions" and "revision history"?

Comment: revision history is the changes you have made and multiple versions refers to different versions of the language I believe

Comment: If you aren't keeping the versions the history is meaningless. Say, you know that user-x changes file a.php, but what was changed? Versions and histories need each other.

Comment: I agree w/ s_ha_dum, you need version control, so if you ever need to go back, you can go back "a version" or to a "specific version" of your files. There is really no way to know keep track of "every single edit I have made to the file" without the project itself becoming a new "version". Perhaps looking into version control with GIT will help to better understand: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control As far as revision history confusing you, you might be comparing GIT with something called Subversion which keeps revision history but has drawbacks that GIT doesn't.

Comment: @RachieVee So your saying git is the only way of doing this?

Comment: This is my personal experience, but I find GIT to be a smarter version control than Subversion. If you want to track changes to files and not revision history as far as posts/page content goes, then you need to use version control whether it be GIT or SVN.

Comment: Also to clarify about GIT, having multiple branches are helpful, but it's not like you have multiple wordpress installations, it's the same files that just change to their "versions" when switching between branches. So if you're on a develop branch and you're working on something that's not complete and you go to your Production branch where everything works and is fine, those files just sort of update to the state they should be in on that branch. So you don't have extra files if that's what worries you.